# Electronic motion due to circular polarization

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation

I came across a question where the situation was of electronic motion of left circular polarized wave in a ionosphere plasma of electron density $3\cdot 10^{11}$ and external magnetic field $B_0$ in $z$ direction. They have said the electric field vector has constant magnitude $E_0$ and also the magnitude of the wave's magnetic field is a lot less than $B_0$. The amplitude of electronic motion is much smaller than wavelength of wave and no collision of electrons is there.

Can anybody explain the trajectory of electron? I can get it that due to electric field it will rotate. But will the radius decrease continuously due to magnetic field? What will be the magnitude of magnetic force?

Comment: Any help please...